# Understanding slow queries from mysqldumpslow

Tags: mysql, php, logging

I'm maintaining a system which sporadically (no exact time) but only at night causes the entire server to crash for a few seconds and the users seeing "Error Connection Refused" until the system restores itself.

The application server is running PHP and PHP-FPM with Nginx.

I've enabled the slow log on the database server and `mysqldumpslow` gave me the following output.

```
Count: 302  Time=44.50s (13439s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), 4users@2hosts
  #

Count: 44  Time=64.65s (2844s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), 3users@2hosts
  COMMIT

Count: 19  Time=82.44s (1566s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=295151.3 (5607875), site-admin[site-admin]@7hosts
  SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `audits`
```

I have a few questions regarding this output and would appreciate if anyone could explain whether these queries could cause both the application and the database server to completely lock up for a few seconds.

1. Are these queries running slow because the query itself is badly written or is it waiting for another query to finish?
2. What are the `COMMIT`, `#` and `SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM 'audits'` queries that seem to be running there?
3. Regarding the last query, I read this comes from a `mysqldump` command that was run on the server. Could this have caused a build up that evertually led to the crashing of both database and application servers?

Comment: Not a mysql expert, but the answers to your questions depend on the actual queries that are running and the server hardware and configuration. Have you already tried the most basic tuning (*mysqltuner.pl*) or is the server still running with defaults?

Comment: Move to stackoverflow.com dba.stackexchange.com -- it's a better place for MySQL questions.

Comment: `mysqldump` is running to make a backup.